# Menu button vanishes once i click somewhere on the screen

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

css code i have added images for each effect ..

```
#button3
   { border:none;
    outline:none;
    width:262px;
     height:66px;
     background:url("settings_button1.png");
     position:absolute;
     margin-left:515px;
     }
#button3:hover
 {
    width:262px;
     height:66px;
     background:url("settings_button2.png");
     } 
#button3:focus
   {

  width:262px;
     height:102px;
     background:url("settings_button3.png");
     }
```

HTML code

```
<html>
 <head>
  </head>
   <body>
     <input type="button" id="button3">
    </body>
   </html>
```

Its working fine but once i click somewhere else on the screen i dont want the drop arrow to go ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').on('focusout', function(){
     $(this).height('102px');
     $(this).css("background-color","blue");
})

$('input').on('focus', function(){
     $(this).height('102px');
     $(this).css("background-color","blue");
})
```

Use your image instead of background color.

[**See the Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nku0thj3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it using jquery. Add this line to your js file.

```
$('input').on('focusout', function(){
    $(this).height('102px');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nku0thj3/

Comment: i tried this but the image changes.As u can see there are 3 seperate images for each action and heights are different. what if i have 3 buttons with seperate images?

Comment: Then add the image to it on focus out. $(this).attr('src', 'link to image');